# DBNull to other types when retrieving data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 app. I make a call to a database, get my data in a dataset and store it in my class. Heres how im storing my data from the dataset

```
                var dt = ds.Tables[0];
                var i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    wt = new WorkTasksDto
                             {
                                 Notes = dr["Notes"].ToString(),
                                 DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DueDate"])
                 }
```

This is my class member:

```
          [DataMember]
            public DateTime? DueDate
            { get; set; }
```

The field DueDate that comes back from sql server is null and thats fine but when i try to store it in my DueDate field in my class i get the following error:

```
 "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"
```

How do fix this error? Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you still using DataSets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `DataRow.IsNull`

```
DueDate = dr.IsNull("DueDate")? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)dr["DueDate"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DueDate = dr["DueDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?) null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DueDate"]);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can remove redundant cast (DateTime?)null , just write null:

DueDate = dr.IsNull("DueDate")? null : (DateTime?)dr["DueDate"]